# What does this code line infer?

Tags: c++, std

I understand that `std::pair` couples two different/same date types. If used as shown under, what does it say ? And what is it useful for in this case ?

```
class A : public B<std::pair<long double, long double>>
```

Thanks.

Comment: That won't compile unless you're using C++0x, since `>>` is greedily parsed to mean bit shift right.  Also: I'm not sure what you're asking.  It means that `A` publicly extends some template `B` instantiated with `std::pair<long double, long double>` as the parameter...but that answer isn't very helpful.

Comment: What Travis said. "And what is it useful for in this case?" -> How can we answer that when there's no other info? That question needs some context at least!

Comment: Providing you understand basic c++ template syntax, the question makes no sense, as it is absolutely incomplete (what is B?)

Comment: @Travis, no need for C++0x usually, good compilers have the "correct" `>>` parsing provided as a compiler extension. Well, at least G++ does :).

Comment: @Kos, @Pedro: True, but it is not part of the standard yet!

Comment: Indeed it's not! I've already said "compiler extension". It's a project decision which specific C++ dialect to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It infers that `B` is a [template class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_class#Templates_in_C.2B.2B), and that `A` [derives from](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_inheritance) the specialization of `B` that works with [pairs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/) of `long doubles`.

One possible use of that pattern would be a generic [complex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) implementation. In that scenario, you would be deriving a class from a generic `complex` type based on `long double` (sometimes more precise than `float` or plain `double`, but bigger):

```
class PreciseComplex
: public GenericComplex<std::pair<long double, long double> >
{
};
```

Specializing on the container allows you to provide your own implementation of `pair` and use, say, `float` instead of `long double`, all within the same class:

```
class FastComplex
: public GenericComplex<YourFasterPair<float, float> >
{
};
```

Comment: Note the space between the '>' characters.  This is required to differentiate from the `>>` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say anything specific, not knowing the semantics behind A and B.

An example: Consider you want a vector of pairs of `double` values. You could make a structure for that (if the pair has a semantic meaning in your code) or, alternatively, just define it as `std::vector<std::pair<long double, long double> >`.

Now if one would want to extend this `std::vector` class (for some reason... not that I recommend it), one would define it as:

```
template<class T>
class MyVector : public std::vector<T> {
    // ...
};
typedef MyVector<std::pair<long double, long double> > MyVectorOfPairsOfDoubles;
```

Or perhaps in a non-generic way (which I find worse):

```
class MyVectorOfPairsOfDoubles : public std::vector<std::pair<long double, long double> >
{
    // ...
};
```

Which looks like the example provided by you.

But that's just an example... I cannot say what's good or what's wrong with the particular design which you are mentioning, until you describe it further (e.g. what's A and what's B?).